# How to deep link HTTPS urls with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I'm developing a React Native app using Expo and I've managed to deep-link a uri to the app, but I don't know how to do it with https urls. Any inputs on how to do it using?

Thanks!

This is the `app.json` to link it to a custom uri:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "navigation-test",
    "slug": "navigation-test",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.whads.clickclcock"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.whads.clickclcock"
    },
    "scheme": "mychat"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us also the container configuration with `uriPrefix`?

Comment: How did you finally managed it?